# Spring social and MVC : what means <mvc:view-controller path="/signin" />?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to understand how Spring social works. I've imported the spring social quickstart 3.0.x from [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart-3.0.x). It's working well. But i don't understand some points such as this:
In controllers.xml file there are :

```
     <mvc:view-controller path="/signin" />
     <mvc:view-controller path="/signout" />
```

1. Why there is no view-name attribute ?
2. Which views will be displayed for each or which controller and which method will be executed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the spring documentation

```
mvc:view-controller registers a ParameterizableViewController that selects 
a view for rendering. In this case, when "/" is requested, the welcome view is  
rendered.The actual view template is a .jsp resolved inside the /WEB-INF/views 
directory.
```

Here if you have registered `<mvc:view-controller path="/signin" />` then it will resolve to `signin.jsp`